# How to edit the element.style css?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, popup

Hi I am using a jquery modal pop up. See picture below.

[image]

However, the problem is, I need to edit the width.
So I typed in the css file, after checking and verifying with firebug,

```
element.style 
{
    width: 700px !important;
}
```

But it does not work. ANy ideas as how to override the jquery css.

Some say the need to edit the css using javascript, making objects and stuff. But I'm not so sure about that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `element` by itself doesn't exist in CSS. You can name that class `.element-style` and add it to the HTML element you want to modify, and that must work. Or, you can name it `div.style` and that would affect only divs that have class `style` in their class attribute.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`element.style` in Firebug is the style applied to the element, for exemple

```
<span style="padding: 10px;">My text</span>
```

`element.style` will have

```
element.style 
{
    padding: 10px;
}
```

to override, the best way is to cleat the `style` attribute, append a `class` name and write the CSS you need.

---

Regarding your modal problem, if you are using [jQuery UI Dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) component, why don't you set the width programmatically, like:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ width: 460, maxWidth: 460, minWidth: 460 });
```

Comment: I followed this http://blog.stevehorn.cc/2009/06/rendering-modal-dialog-with-aspnet-mvc.html tutorial, How should I override element.style

Comment: Again, your problem is not the **overriding** part, it's how to use the **jQuery UI Dialog**!

Comment: might be true but I used the following css .ui-dialog{width: 550px !important;} 

.ui-widget{width: 550px !important;} 

.ui-widget-content{width: 550px !important ;}

.ui-draggable{width: 550px !important;} 

.ui-resizable{width: 550px !important;} AND IT WORKED

Comment: you need to STOP hacking stuff that works out of the box, and learn how to use it... if works today... tomorrow, when you have all setup, or in 6 month you need to edit and you know stuff better you will have a hard time finding that hack! And you will pass a lot of time wondering what's wrong! Think about the **future**, do things right since the first time!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to clear the width from the `<div>` element itself. It is flagged as important so you can't override it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

The div [style^= is the Div 'Element Style' where you are able to modify any CSS Element.

For Example: If the actual 'Element Style' width is 300px.

```
div [style^="width: 300px"]{
     width:700px !important;}
```

This forces to overwrite the Element Style to width 700px.

Answer (score 0):

element.style is not a valid CSS selector. You would have to target the element using it's class or id, if it has one, otherwise you'd need to use traversal to target the element in either CSS, or with jQuery.